# Usage of Put() or Get()

Tags: solidity, remix

Are both of these methods deprecated? I saw an example with it being used as so:

```
function whatIsPut() payable {
put();
}
```

It is described as being required to 'put' ether into the contract. As of solidity 0.4.22 (what I am using, most likely earlier) I know this is not necessary and

```
function SureIsntNeeded() public payable {}
```

achieves the same thing.

I am not sure of `get()`, but I haven't been able to find either in the documentation.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation you're talking about? Is it this: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#db_gethex and this: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#db_puthex

Comment: @ThomasJayRush It's solidity's so it would be this: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/

Comment: Can you point to the put and get parts of the documentation?  The reason I’m asking is because I think put and get are not part of Solidity, and the depreciation note you’re referring to is related to these RPC calls. I may be wrong, which is why I’m asking for clarification.

Comment: They don't seem to be. Even in earlier versions. So where could I look for the rpc calls, and how do they tie into solidity. Please excuse my lack of understanding

Comment: No problem. I linked to the RPC docs above. RPC = remote procedure call. It’s an API for querying the Ethereum node. You can use curl for example.